Why does adding a calculated dimension in Looker Studio table change session value from Google Analytics 4?
I have a Looker Studio table connected to GA4 with the dimension “Year month” in the first column and the metric “Sessions” in the second column. My date range is set to the previous month, so my table has only one row. The number of sessions matches what I can see in the GA4 user interface.
However, when I add a new column to the table based on a calculated dimension, the number of sessions changes.
My calculated dimension is based on this formula:
FORMAT_DATETIME("%Y-%m", DATETIME_ADD(Date, INTERVAL 1 YEAR))
After I add this new column, I still have only one row, but the number of sessions has changed.
Does anyone know why this is happening?
